# cast debugging custom receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to follow the instruction in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging).  But I am not seeing the inspect link as described in step 4.

I do get a list of all chrome cast devices on the network (including the one I'm casting to), with there IP addresses but no Inspect link as described in step 4.

There is a button labeled 'Open dedicated DevTools for Node' right above the list of chrome cast devices but this opens a console which is not attached to any page or give any response to any command.

It dose load the custom receiver properly, so I don't think it's a registration problem.  It will disconnect after about 30 sec which is what I'm ultimately trying to debug.

I have tried restarting the Chromecast as well and it is up to date.

Maybe I'm missing something but any suggestions on what to try next would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: what does your Receiver Application URL look like?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too.
I resolved it by connecting via WiFi, not ethernet.
Then the inspect link has appeared.
[here is my question at productforums.google.com](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/chromecast/a65f58e3-bd61-46ae-84f0-f2b2b8cf56b6%40googleproductforums.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)